# Positiong an element with absolute positiong without expanding the parent

Tags: css

I have a relative positioned div and I want to position its child using absolute positioning - easy. One question though: I was under the impression absolute positioned children dont take up any space, but if I position it right:5000px for example a huge gap appears to the right to accommodate that element. 
How do I position an element as absolute say 5000px to the right from its parent without the parent expanding to take up the room to accomodate both.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: They don't take up space in the parent *as far as other elements are concerned* but the browser still has to paint them somewhere in relation to the **screen**. The parent isn't expanding...the page is.

Comment: Thank you. So you can't hide it off the edge of the page without the scroll bar appearing?

Comment: Sure buut you have to tell the page not to overflow with `body {overflow-x:hidden;}`. But this has its own issues. A proper example of whhat it is you are trying to do would be ideal. We don't usual hide things that want any more...there are better options.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you do it..the parent shouldn't get expanded.
Here's an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/0oofcd0x/1/

```
container{
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  height:200px;
  width: 500px;
}
.internal{
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  left: 800px;
}
```

Comment: In your example the internal is off the edge of the screen but there is a scroll bar at the bottom as the window is larger - this is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Oh I understand now...
So what exactly do you need?

If you don't have a scroll..you will be never able too see it.
It sounds like you wanna make it display: none

I still don't understand the purpose of making it left:5000

Comment: Thanks - I now understand that it is the page not the parent element which is getting larger - I had an issue where I was pushing an element half way off the edge of the container and it was forcing the page to scroll - Thanks for your help!